# Update entry while iterating through key set

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator

How would you accomplish updating the an entry while iterating through the keys

```
Map<String,List<SObject>> Map1=new HashMap<String,List<SObject>>();
Map<String,List<SObject>> Map2=new HashMap<String,List<SObject>>();

for(String name: Map1.keyset()){
//do something

   for(SObject obj1: Map1.get(name)){
    //iterate through the list of SObjects returned for the key 

        for(SObject obj2 : Map2.get(name)){
        //iterate through the list of SObject values for the keys and update or remove the values related to the key
        }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Iterator on the map's entrySet - map.entrySet().iterator()

Make sure nothing else is modifying the map while you're iterating through it, but your own modifications will be safe as long as you:

```
- only remove items using the iterator's remove() method, and
- only modify a value by using the Map.Entry setValue() method
```

See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

To modify the collection during iteration you'll want to use the `ListIteration` interface:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html